# Non functioning php wildcard search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to make a website but my wildcard search query keeps giving me issues.

It doesn't show any errors but the result appears blank. 
You can view it live here at this website: [luke.dx.am/Search.php](http://luke.dx.am/Search.php)

Her is my code for the search bar.

```
<!-- Custom Search -->
<form action="Search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input type="submit" value=">>"/>
</form>
```

Here is my code that executes the search query.

```
<?php
$output = '';
$searchq = '';
$search_query = '';
$search_results = '';
$result = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

//Query for the search engine
$search_query = "SELECT Item.Item, Category.Category, Colour.Colour, 
Description.Description, products.Price, products.Stock, products.date, 
Sexs.Sex, Sizes.Size, Designers.Designer, Designers.Email, 
Designers.Phone, Designers.Address, Image.Image
FROM products
INNER JOIN Category 
ON Category.CatagoryCode=products.CatagoryCode
INNER JOIN Colours 
ON Colour.ColourCode=products.CatagoryCode
INNER JOIN Description
ON Description.DescriptionCode=products.DescriptionCode
INNER JOIN Designers
ON Designers.DesignerCode=products.DescriptionCode
INNER JOIN Sexs 
ON Sexs.SexCode=products.SexCode
INNER JOIN Image 
ON Image.ImageCode=products.ItemCode
INNER JOIN Item 
ON Item.ItemCode=products.ItemCode
INNER JOIN Sizes
ON Sizes.SizeCode=products.SizeCode  
WHERE Item.Item LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Category.Category LIKE '%$searchq%' 
OR Colour.Colour LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Description.Description LIKE 
'%$searchq%' OR Sexs.Sex LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Sizes.Size LIKE 
'%$searchq%' OR Designers.Designer LIKE '%$searchq%'";

$search_results=mysqli_query($con, $search_query);
if($result == FALSE) { 
?><p>Error</p><?php
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}else{

//Runs in a while loop

while($output=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
```

Sorry for the absolute wall of code.

Comment: there is already mysql warnings shows in your home page

Comment: it should be search_result right?

Comment: @result i think

Comment: `$search_results != $result`. Pick one and change the other. Also, `mysql_error()` is depreciated in PHP 5.x and removed in PHP 7.x

Comment: Fixed the error on the home page.

Comment: What error was it and how did you fix it? Does it work now?

Comment: The home page works fine, but it wasn't part of the original problem.

Comment: Use mysqli_error(). Double check if the code jumps into the if or else after executing query. Can you post the rest of the fetch code? Do other queries work? And is the connection code working? Are all php errors displayed?

Comment: Does (procedural style) mysqli example code work with your setup? See http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: I noticed your website works again. Can you share with us what the problem was and how you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your code. You are getting the result in $search_results and then checking it in $result.

```
$search_results=mysqli_query($con, $search_query);
if($result == FALSE) { ...
```

Needs to be

```
$search_results=mysqli_query($con, $search_query);
if($search_results == FALSE) {...
```

Comment: You also need to change mysqli_fetch_array to use $search_results instead of $result. Another tip is to echo $search_query and then use the query in a MySQL client and run it and to see if it shows up any records

Comment: Also ran the query in PHP MyAdmin and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First apply a name to your submit button.

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=">>"/>
```

Second check to see if it isset(clicked) then process the form.

```
<?php
$search_results=mysqli_query($con, $search_query);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Check for results like this no need to use $result == FALSE.  The ! is like saying not(if not results)

```
if(!$search_results){ 
?><p>Error</p><?php
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}else{
```

//Runs in a while loop

```
while($output= $search_results->fetch_assoc()) {
$outputA = $output['tableNamea'];
$outputB = $output['TanbeNameb'];
}
```

Whole thing

```
<?php
$search_results=mysqli_query($con, $search_query);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!$search_results){ 
?><p>Error</p><?php
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}else{
while($output= $search_results->fetch_assoc()) {
$outputA = $output['tableNamea'];
$outputB = $output['TanbeNameb'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the query supposed to go in this?